# What word do Americans use for dirt?

Tags: american-english, british-english, speech

I'm aware that in America the word "dirt" is a synonym/replacement for earth/soil/peat/turf.etc whereas in the UK "dirt" would typically refer to uncleanliness, detritus, and granular rubbish (i.e. too small to pick up by hand). You wouldn't say your garden was full of dirt in the UK.

What word do Americans use to refer to the type of granular rubbish that is typically referred to by the UK use of the word "dirt", unless "dirt" fills both uses in America? After all, "dirty" seems to mean the same thing, either side of the Atlantic.

Comment: As an American, it sounds to me like you’re describing ***litter***.

Comment: Interesting link for Brits - the 'sweptyard' as opposed to the 'dirtyard' both of which are unknown in the UK, as such. We have 'gravel' yards, usually. [Link](http://www.thegardeningdiva.com/swept-yards.html). 'Dirt' or 'dirty' in BrE (I would say) is not just something that can be swept up. It bears a connotation of requiring washing in order to cleanse it, whether physically or morally.

Comment: Additionally, would this word be universally common across all American states, or are there regional differences?

Comment: @DanBron 'Litter' is normally limited to paper, empty cans and the like which have been dropped in a public place. 'Dirt' in the British sense could include mud (on paving or indoors), animal droppings, decayed leaves and the like.

Comment: @KateBunting You could say the yard is *dirty* for those things, but they are not included in the noun *dirt* (except for animal droppings, which can be called, eg. *dog dirt*, in a distinct sense of the word from *soil*). I’m not aware of any common noun which can be used to refer to bits of paper, empty cans, animal droppings, dead leaves, and so on, but you could use *detritus* (it’s accurate and understandable, but a bit latinate / high-falutin’ for day to day use).

Comment: Could you give an example sentence (or even several), and perhaps a brief description of how you would say  UK "dirt" differs in meaning from some of the synonyms given by a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/dirt?s=t) (e.g. "crud", "dreck", "filth", "gunk")?

Comment: @NigelJ We tend to use 'yard' only for enclosed, paved spaces though, like a backyard or a farmyard (is that a 'sweptyard'?) The Americans seem to use it for what we would call a 'garden' as in 'front garden' and 'back garden' (which I imagine to be a 'dirtyard'). Do Americans use 'garden' only for larger, more formal spaces?

Comment: @sumelic I don't think UK 'dirt' does differ in meaning. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dirt gives the 'filth' definition first. It's just that we don't normally use the word to mean garden soil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an American, I think this is dependent on context:

- **Dust** if in a building
- **Crumbs** if involving food
- **Grime** if non-granular (especially if membranous)

In all other contexts (and arguably in some of the ones listed above) it would not be unusual for an American to simply say **dirt**.

> "Clean the *dirt* off the porch."
>
> "I wiped the *dirt* off the park bench."

Perhaps one might also make a more indirect reference to such filth using the word **mess**, but this term is used more generally and could include any of large *and* small granular filth, membranous filth, or even larger trash or clutter.

Comment: You actually use 'grime' quite often? In the UK, there's a more ingrained, probably almost sinister and corruption-generated aspect to 'grime', and it's not used very often unless invoking say the dark satanic mill setting.

Comment: @Edwin. often? Probably not, but not too uncommonly. `Grime` usually applies to mold/mildew/scum/food-residues that grow or are stuck to counters, tiles, tubs, etc. As in "I've got to go clean the grime out of the sink"

Comment: That's pretty much in line with the normal usage over here. _Thanks_.